# Translation of "Qua de causa"

Tags: classical-latin, word-order, style, gaius-iulius-caesar

This is a from the very beginning of the Caesar's *De Bello Gallico*.

The first question is about its translation as "For which reason". In English, it's supposed to be in a single sentence , e.g. "He was brave, for which reason, he won.", while in Latin it is divided into two: "... continenter bellum gerunt. Qua de causa...". Is this proper in Latin, or just Caesar's own writing style?

The second question is about the word order. I get that in Latin hyperbaton is widely applied, so is it also proper to say "De qua causa", or the word "qua" should always be placed at the beginning? Or does it depend on the word class of "qua" in this sentence, since it can be used as a stand-alone adverb, or as declined "qui" in the relative clause?

Comment: Please note that Caesar's personal writing style (together with a few others, naturally) more or less defines what is and isn't “good, classical Latin.” Doesn't mean he doesn't have distinctive personal habits (like his extensive use of the ablative absolute), but this isn't one of them.

Comment: On another note: There is absolutely no reason to think that “in English, it's supposed to be in a single sentence,” and the fact that it's two sentences in Latin indicates it's *probably* a good idea to make it two sentences in English as well. It may be a little more idiomatic in English to start the second sentence with “For this reason” and not “For which reason,” but that isn't Caesar's problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Latin, unlike English, you can start a sentence with a relative pronoun that refers to the whole previous sentence or thought.
A more natural translation than "which" is "that" or "it".
At the start of a sentence I'd therefore translate *qua de causa* as "for that reason" or simply "therefore".
This is not an unusual phenomenon in Latin literature.

Also, it's not unusual to put a preposition between two words like that.
In my experience it's particularly common with the relative pronoun, but it's not limited to it.
The option *de qua causa* would have been grammatical but probably less idiomatic.

The practice of dividing a text up to well defined sentences with full stops was not observed in antiquity the way it is today.
The Romans didn't always indicate where sentences change, whence the question whether the relative pronoun that confuses you in Caesar really comes in a separate new sentence is pretty moot.
The punctuation is not due to Caesar himself but to later editors and copiers.
But this doesn't undermine the point I started with:
The textual tradition that preserves these texts to us comes with punctuation that makes relative continuation like this pretty common.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the Romans did not usually mark sentence ends, so the distinction between such a “relative continuation” and a run-on sentence was presumably rather murky.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Good point! I added a paragraph.